# Android Webview - How to load HTML file contains remote JS and CSS files from Multiple sources

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

How to load HTML file in Android Webview with external JS and CSS files from multiple sources.

I know we can use **loadDataWithBaseURL** for loading files from one source. But my JS and CSS files are placed in different sources. Here the HTML file I want to load in Android Web view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
                <title>Test</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks...